# Ошибка в поиске MySQL (Пробелы и Цифры)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных

Здравствуйте, делаю киносайт прикрутил поиск, но возникла очень странная ошибка.
При запросе "**Мажор 2**" и любого другого запроса такого формата (**Крестный отец 2,Крестный отец 3**) ничего не выдает через запрос в PHP.Пробывал искать напрямую через phpMyAdmin, но там тоже не находит, хотя в базе фильмы есть.
Думал что дело в наличии цифр, но потом ввел "**1408**" и он отлично нашел фильм.
А если ввожу запрос без цифр и пробелов например "**Мажор**" или "**Крестный отец**", то все выводится в куче с другими результатами где было вхождение.

```
$search = $_POST['q'];
$getName = mysql_query("select id,name_ru,name_en,year,description from all_list
WHERE CONCAT (name_ru,name_en) LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY kp_rating DESC LIMIT 5");
```

У полей тип "Text", сравнение "utf8_general_ci".
Пожалуйста помогите разобраться.

Comment: "Крестный отец" - это без цифр и пробелов?)

Comment: Да  это без цифр и пробелов

Comment: А между первым и вторым словом - это что за символ, не подскажете?)

Comment: Если пробел между словами то поиск работает нормально (напр.Крестный отец), а вот если в конце между словом и цифрой, то ничего не находит (напр.Крестный отец 2).

Comment: А в базе точно перед цифрами стоит один пробел?

Comment: `$search = mysql_escape_string($_POST['q']);` - на поиск может и не повлияет, но защитит от инъекции

Comment: Да один пробел.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50990/discussion-between-p-fateev-and-yaslik).

Comment: В любом случае надо переходить на "полнотекстовый поиск" (забить в гугле). Если по каким то причинам это не возможно, то делать свой поисковый велосипед. Разбивать все тексты которые есть в названиях и в описаниях на отдельные слова, делать словарь с ID у каждого слова и поисковую таблицу где под каждый фильм будет набор строк с id встречающихся слов и их позиций в предложениях. При поиске разбивать поисковую фразу на слова и одним запросом находить все фильмы где эти отдельные слова встречаются и сортировать по количеству найденных слов и тому, рядом ли стоят слова

Comment: И раз like не находит - значит у вас все таки где то не пробел. Выгрузите БД в текстовый файл и внимательно в дампе посмотрите. Несколько пробелов на web будут выглядеть как 1 (а вы уже ничего не найдете) и в UTF8 десятки разных символов на экране выглядят как пробел

Comment: В БД все в порядке[ссылка]https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B01gaXFQDLhzbFl5VVFhN3pPTTA/view

Comment: Нашел вот это в бд [ссылка]https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B01gaXFQDLhzWU0zYTEtUmRrb3M/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том что когда добавлял данные в базу прописал htmlspecialchars и поэтому добавлялся "`&nbsp;`".
Сделал полный UPDATE базы и теперь все в порядке.
Для замены "`&nbsp;`" использовал:

```
$stroka = htmlentities($row['stroka'], null, 'utf-8');
$stroka = str_replace("&nbsp;",' ',$stroka );
$stroka = html_entity_decode($stroka);
```